# open pdf from base64 in ionic

Tags: angular, pdf, ionic3

So I have Jasper reports that I convert to pdf, then to base64 in a REST controller.  How do I go about transferring this to my ionic 3 app? I've looked into the Ionic Native Document Viewer, but in order to do this, I would need to transfer the file to the app.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you like to open pdf in Ionic app you have to first save file in local storage and then open it.
Basically you need two Ionic Native plugins and some base64 to blob converter:

Import (in component and in app.module) this dependencies:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/

Next inject in your components constructor:

```
private opener: FileOpener,
private file: File,
```

then get your pdf data from REST service as base64 (string) and execute this function:

```js
saveAndOpenPdf(pdf: string, filename: string) {
  const writeDirectory = this.platform.is('ios') ? this.file.dataDirectory : this.file.externalDataDirectory;
  this.file.writeFile(writeDirectory, filename, this.convertBase64ToBlob(pdf, 'data:application/pdf;base64'), {replace: true})
    .then(() => {
        this.opener.open(writeDirectory + filename, 'application/pdf')
            .catch(() => {
                console.log('Error opening pdf file');
            });
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.error('Error writing pdf file');
    });
}
```

And convert function from base64 to blob (need for saving file on disk):

```js
convertBase64ToBlob(b64Data, contentType): Blob {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    const sliceSize = 512;
    b64Data = b64Data.replace(/^[^,]+,/, '');
    b64Data = b64Data.replace(/\s/g, '');
    const byteCharacters = window.atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];
    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
         const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
         const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
         for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
             byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
         }
         const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
         byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
   return new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
}
```

Comment: Your code works if i change "this.convertBase64ToBlob(pdf, 'data:application/pdf;base64')" to: "this.convertBase64ToBlob(pdf, 'application/pdf')" because new Blob expect the second parameter to be a valid mimetype format

Comment: Is it possible to open the Base64 URL pdf without saving the actual file?

Comment: I'm almost sure that you have to save it first. Here is some article for reference: 
https://ionicacademy.com/open-pdf-ionic-4/